# How can I display my array from this line of code?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<script>

var a = 33;
var b = 6;

var famList = [a, b];

function famDisp (){
  for (var i=0, num=famList.length; i<num; i++){
    famList[i];
  }
}

famDisp(famList);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to display the array famList but I am not getting any result.
Using console.log to display I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: famList is undefined"
What have I been doing wrong?

Comment: where do you use `console.log`? I don't see it in the code provided.

Comment: Currently, your function `famList` doesn't do anything.

Comment: To "display" values (you probably mean "inject into the DOM" instead), it's not enough to simply loop through the array and hope that mentioning `famList[i]` somehow magically makes the values appear somewhere.

Comment: My bad. @Gereon can't believe i missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed parameter in **famDisp ()**  so  replaced

```
famDisp ()
```

TO

```
 famDisp (famList)
```

then it will be work perfectly

```js
var a = 33;
var b = 6;

var famList = [a, b];

function famDisp (famList){
  for (var i=0, num=famList.length; i<num; i++){
    famList[i];
      
      console.log(famList[i])
  }
}

famDisp(famList);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
Html code

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like Gereon answered:
"To "display" values (you probably mean "inject into the DOM" instead), it's not enough to simply loop through the array and hope that mentioning famList[i] somehow magically makes the values appear somewhere. "

Yours explains further too. Jazaakallahu khair.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is where to write the console.log just write it wherever you wanted it to be in the script tag. but if you want to display the values in the browser window then the concept if "document.getlementby'id , class name or tagnmae '" should be applied.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <h1 id="ht-tag">display the result here </h1>

    <script>

        var a = 33;
        var b = 6;

        var famList = [a, b];
        let num = famList.length
        function famDisp() {
            for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                famList[i];
                console.log(famList[i])
                text = document.createTextNode(famList[i] + " ,")
                document.getElementById("ht-tag").appendChild(text)

            }
        }


        famDisp(famList);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```